# Silverlight property binding

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone-7

Could Someone help me to find out why l.X1 is set to default value(0.0) when the binded source is having a value of 156. Following image may be self explanatory.

[image]

Comment: Is everything declared and running on the same thread? My guess is probably not and that's why you're seeing this behaviour. WOuld need more code to help - sorry.

Comment: Everything is declared and on same thread.

Comment: If I comment out following lines in my MyObj class everything works as expected.But I need this property to be dependency property.  public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterXProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CenterX", typeof(double), typeof(MyObj), null);
        
public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterYProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CenterY", typeof(double), typeof(MyObj), null);

Comment: Show us your declaration for the X1Property DependencyProperty.  Also, show us the bindings to the CenterX DependencyProperty.

Comment: I'm using the same Line class provided by framework.The only binding I am using are there in the image in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These missing lines in the CLR set methods were causing that odd result. In set methods I played with a different attached property. SetValue(CenterXProperty, value); SetValue(CenterYProperty, value);

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/66005.aspx

I don't think you can use a DependencyProperty as a BindingSource in SilverLight.  See the link above.

Comment: Just curious,Why Framworkelement exposes a method named SetBinding(dp,binding).when it is not supported

Comment: My understanding is the WPF does support SetBinding() to DependencyProperty objects in the Binding.Source, but that Silverlight does not. I won't swear to it, though.  Can you mock up a test with WPF?

Comment: These missing lines in the CLR set methods were causing that odd result. In set methods I played with a different attached property.

SetValue(CenterXProperty, value);

SetValue(CenterYProperty, value);